# What is the meaning of "modest in scope"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

this the context:

> this paper was **modest in scope**.

I think I understand it but I wanna be sure. I think the meaning of that is:

> the range of paper was limited.

Am I right and if not, can you explain the meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does mean that the range of the paper was limited. But by using the word *modest* instead of *limited*, it makes it less likely to be taken as an insult. This is because the word *modest* has a generally positive connotation.

See the definitions of modest at [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/modest):

> 1a : placing a moderate estimate on one's abilities or worth
>   1b : neither bold nor self-assertive : tending toward diffidence
>   2 : arising from or characteristic of a modest nature
>   3 : observing the proprieties of dress and behavior : decent
>   4a : limited in size, amount, or scope
>   4b : unpretentious

The definition in use here is probably closest to 4a (which does use the word *limited*), but if you look at all of the other definitions, they are generally good things.